# Disable the Bootbox close button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'm wondering how remove the "X" button that shows up on [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html) alerts, confirms, prompts and dialogs.

There are cases where you'd wish to require the user to provide a response--not just dismiss the pop-up with a click on the "X" button.

Does anyone have an idea of how to remove this button?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution, and it is fairly easy (but doesn't seem to be in the current Bootbox documentation.)

The solution works for Bootbox Dialogs, so if you need to remove the "X" for other types of boxes, I'd suggest imitating the other, more primitive types of boxes as a dialog.

The solution, which uses `closeButton: false`, is seen in the snippet below:

```
        bootbox.dialog({
            closeButton: false,
            title: "Woah this acts like an alert",
            message: "Cool info for you. You MUST click Ok.",
            buttons: {
                success:{
                    label: "Ok",
                    callback: callback
                }
            }       
        });

       callback(){//stuff that happens when they click Ok.}
```

By making sure the user must click on a button to dismiss the box, we can make sure they trigger an appropriate callback function.

Comment: Now this is included in Bootbox [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#dialog-options)